SwiftData Update Causing EXC_BAD_ACCESS Crash in SwiftUI App
I'm developing a SwiftUI application using SwiftData and I'm encountering a EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash when trying to update certain data in my app. Specifically, the crash occurs when I try to update the highlight attribute of TextSeg objects.
Here's the relevant code in my CommentStore class:
import Combine
import Foundation
import SwiftData
import SwiftUI

@Observable
final class CommentStore: Sendable {
    //...

    func createHighlight() async throws {
        //...
        let textSegs = try await swiftDataService.fetchTextSegsBetween(startTimeMs: self.timeStart!, endTimeMs: self.timeEnd!, conversationId: conversationId)
        // set all highlight attributes to true for the textSegs
        let date = Date()

        for textSeg in textSegs {
            // this line crashes the app with EXC_BAD_ACCESS
            textSeg.highlight = true
        }

        try await swiftDataService.updateEverything()
        cleanUpState()
    }

    func removeHighlight() async throws {
        //...
        let textSegs = try await swiftDataService.fetchTextSegsBetween(startTimeMs: self.timeStart!, endTimeMs: self.timeEnd!, conversationId: conversationId)

        for textSeg in textSegs {
            // this line crashes the app with EXC_BAD_ACCESS
            textSeg.highlight = false
        }

        try await swiftDataService.updateEverything()
        cleanUpState()
    }
}



import Foundation
import SwiftData

@Model
class TextSegSD: Identifiable {
    @Attribute(.unique) var id: UUID = UUID()
    var text: String
    var timeStart: Int
    var timeEnd: Int
    @Relationship var conversation: ConversationSD?
    @Relationship var backupConversation: ConversationSD?
    // update this
    var highlight: Bool = false //
    var createdAt: Date = Date.now

    init(text: String, timeStart: Int, timeEnd: Int, conversation: ConversationSD? = nil, backupConversation: ConversationSD? = nil, highlight: Bool = false) {
        self.text = text
        self.timeStart = timeStart
        self.timeEnd = timeEnd
        self.conversation = conversation
        self.backupConversation = backupConversation
        self.highlight = highlight
    }
}

The crash consistently occurs on the lines where I update the highlight property of TextSeg objects.
What I've Observed

The crash is not consitantly reproducible, it happen randomly, even with the same textSegSD, it could crash or not crash.

What I've Tried

Ensured that the fetched textSegs are valid and not nil.
Verified that swiftDataService.updateEverything() works correctly without the highlight updates.
Reviewed related documentation and similar issues, but haven't found a definitive solution.

Alternative Solution
As a workaround, I've considered deleting the TextSeg objects and recreating them with the updated attributes. This method avoids the crash, but it's not an ideal solution for my use case.
Questions

What could be causing the EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash when updating the highlight attribute?
Are there any best practices for updating suite data in Swift to avoid such crashes?
Is there a more efficient and safe workaround than deleting and recreating the TextSeg objects?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Observable is not Sendable, to you have to manage thread safety yourself when marking a class as Sendable. A global actor is the simplest way of doing this.

@loremipsum @JoakimDanielson Thanks for looking into it, I changed it to actor

actor CommentStore {

//everything else keep the same.

}

I still got the issue.
Any further suggestion ?

We don’t have much to go on, it is more than likely a threading issue. At this point I would guess it might be with the context but you don’t have any context code here.

@loremipsum thanks for the guideness, currently I did a walkaround by deleting the old one and creating new one.
I will do some research and if i found the root cause I will come back and update it.

An option would be to use a background context for the editing instead of the main context. My guess is that the UI or something else is using the same object somewhere else.
